# Swing an image by using j Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to swing an image using jQuery. I have gone through so many tutorials but I was unable to find out how to do this.

Comment: Please show your code effort

Comment: try using jquery animate but the object is your image (ex : img#pict1 ) reference : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: hell yahh.... I found it.. its relay awesome....here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can do it using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCWE/1193/

```
bod{
  background:blue;
}

.box{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-animation:swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin:top;
}
@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-500deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(500deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-500deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-500deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(500deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-500deg)}
}
```

hope it's helps.